# SQL query to break down day by day for entire week

Tags: mysql

I have a table of sales in MySQL. I'm trying in 1 query to get a view that looks like this:

```
AGENT, MONDAY_TOTAL, TUESDAY_TOTAL,WEDNESDAY_TOTAL,THURSDAY_TOTAL,FRIDAY_TOTAL,SATURDAY_TOTAL
```

What I have so far is this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(repname), DAYOFWEEK(sub_date), COUNT(*) 
FROM `NewDeals` 
WHERE WEEK(sub_date) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE) 
GROUP BY repname, DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)
```

That gives me values that look like this:

```
AGENT, DAYOFWEEK, TOTAL
```

Naturally, I can turn the output of the second example into the first in my code, but if I can just do it with the SQL query I'd rather do that.

```
SELECT repname, 
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=2, 1, 0)) AS MONDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=3, 1, 0)) AS TUESDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=4, 1, 0)) AS WEDNESDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=5, 1, 0)) AS THURSDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=6, 1, 0)) AS FRIDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=7, 1, 0)) AS SATURDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=1, 1, 0)) AS SUNDAY_TOTAL
FROM `NewDeals` 
WHERE WEEK(sub_date) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE) 
GROUP BY repname
```

But getting results for days that haven't happened yet.

Update: This was because we did not constrain the year:

Solution:

```sql
SELECT repname, 
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=2, 1, 0)) AS MONDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=3, 1, 0)) AS TUESDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=4, 1, 0)) AS WEDNESDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=5, 1, 0)) AS THURSDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=6, 1, 0)) AS FRIDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=7, 1, 0)) AS SATURDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=1, 1, 0)) AS SUNDAY_TOTAL
FROM `NewDeals` 
WHERE WEEK(sub_date) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE) AND YEAR(sub_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY repname
```

Comment: you need to generate a sub table which has the days then do a join on that and a sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IF` function to select only `DAYOFWEEK`-related counts, then sum every counted element inside the `SUM` aggregate function as follows:

```
SELECT repname, 
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=2, 1, 0)) AS MONDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=3, 1, 0)) AS TUESDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=4, 1, 0)) AS WEDNESDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=5, 1, 0)) AS THURSDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=6, 1, 0)) AS FRIDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=7, 1, 0)) AS SATURDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=1, 1, 0)) AS SUNDAY_TOTAL
FROM `NewDeals` 
WHERE WEEK(sub_date) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE) 
GROUP BY repname
```

Note: when the `DISTINCT` keyword is applied, it will work on every selected field of your `SELECT` clause, you can't make a distinct of a single field using parentheses.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS MONDAY_TOTAL,
       SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(sub_date)=2, 1, 0) AS TUESDAY_TOTAL,
' at line 2

Comment: Never mind i got it , missing the second ) at end of if statement

Comment: Also  u have sun and mon as same date, monday is 2 in MYSQL

Comment: After fixing the ) and the date values, I'm getting returns for Friday and Saturday.... Seeing as its only thursday i'm going to assume there's scope error in our selection....

Comment: Can you share your data by updating your post?

Comment: We only checking week numbers! we're getting data for other years because we didnt constrain the year only the week

Comment: Try adding `AND YEAR(sub_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)` to the `WHERE` clause.